# Checkout sample code from chromium.org with SVN

Tags: svn, chromium

For instance [this page](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/). How to download all files to local?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `viewvc` part from URL of page

```
svn co http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction
```